# Finding the path for an image in Moodle 3.7

Tags: php, google-chrome, moodle

I have a Moodle 3.7 installation in my localhost (Ubuntu 19.04, Apache2, PostgreSQL, PHP 7.2). I want to change some icons in the theme, and I'm trying to find the exact folder where the icons are stored.

When I click F12 in Google Chrome and point to the specific image I want to change, I see this:

```
<img class="icon " alt="" aria-hidden="true" src="http://localhost/moodle/theme/image.php/lambda/core/1556073422/i/duration">
```

So, the path for this image is showing some PHP file. I've opened the PHP file and could not guess where is the image in my folders.

How can I find the true path for this image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image your're looking for is 
`[Moodleroot]/pix/i/duration.png` or `[Moodleroot]/pix/i/duration.svg`.

It may be overriden inside a theme if you create a image file and place it in

`[Moodleroot]/theme/[theme name]/pix_core/i/duration.png` or `[Moodleroot]/theme/[theme name]/pix_core/i/duration.svg`

Make sure you purge all caches from Moodle to apply the changes.